# How to prevent rewrite .htaccess file conflict problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ product-details.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1
```

what I have already tried
This is my htaccess file. problem is when I am trying to execute (`infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1`) its move to (`category.php?slug=$1`) conflict with first rule of htaccess.

I tired multiple rewrite methods but its not working. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: You have the same `RewriteRule` _pattern_ in the 1st and 3rd rules so this is obviously a red flag. The first rule will naturally take priority and the 3rd rule is never triggered. However, you've not actually stated the URLs you are requesting. How would _you_ (the human) determine whether a request for `/abcd` should be rewritten to `category.php?slug=abcd` or to `infrastucture-details.php?slug=abcd`? This needs to be deduced from the requested URL only. Once _you_ have answered this then you can begin to write the necessary rule(s) to handle the request.

Comment: http://localhost/project/category.php?slug=pump
http://localhost/project/infrastructure-details.php?slug=paint

second url i want to be-> http://localhost/project/paint

both page is different. can you please specify how to write rules for this different pages.

Comment: You need to place more specific rewriting rules further atop. Keep in mind that those rules are processed from top to bottom. So first the specific exceptions like your URL `/paint`, then more general rewriting rules. And also you want to add some terminating flags like `END` or `L` to your rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^infrastructure/([^/]+)$ infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ product-details.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

This is work fine for me. (infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1 [L]) put on top.

Answer (score 2):

> `localhost/project/category.php?slug=pump`, `localhost/project/infrastructure-details.php?slug=paint` second url i want to be-> `localhost/project/paint` both page is different. can you please specify how to write rules for this different pages.

There is no discernible *pattern* that differentiates these two URLs so the only way to implement these two rewrites is to hardcode them. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^pump$ category.php?slug=$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^paint$ infrastructure-details.php?slug=$0 [L]
```

Where the `$0` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the entire match by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (just saves some repetition).

If you need a more general solution (as your directives suggest) then there needs to be a discernible pattern in the URL that differentiates URLs that should be rewritten to `category.php` and `infrastructure-details.php` respectively.

I'm assuming your `.htaccess` file, and other files, are is inside the `/project` subdirectory.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ category.php?slug=$1
> RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ product-details.php?slug1=$1&slug=$2
>
> RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1
> ```

Rule #1 and #3 conflict - they use exactly the same *pattern* (regex) to match against the requested URL. The first rule is always going to "win" and rewrite the request *before* rule#3 is able to process the request, so rule#3 never matches.

To write a generic rule like this there needs to be a discernible difference between the URL types that you can match with a pattern/regex. For example:

```
/category/pump
/infrastructure/paint
```

And then you can construct rules...

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)$ category.php?slug=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^infrastructure/([^/]+)$ infrastructure-details.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Note that the order of these directives can be important. More specific rules need to be before more generalised rules.